# Is "Any Given Sunday" first movie to cast actor from movie which seen in same movie?

Tags: first-appearance, any-given-sunday

In "**Any Given Sunday**", there is scene between Tony D & Willie at Tony D place, where Tony watching **Ben Hur (1959)** in TV.

[image]

Later into the movie, Charlton Heston who was in Ben Hur is seen as the AFFA Football Commissioner shown talking to Christina.

[image]

Comment: At the least, Last Action Hero did it before Any Given Sunday; though in that case it was more of a fourth wall joke. Same with Space Balls.

Comment: But My question is completely different.

Comment: Not sure how? Both of the movies I mentioned have an actor who is also in a movie mentioned within that movie.

Comment: Almost certainly not but tracking down the first example would be extremely difficult.

Comment: It doesn't matter one way or the other, the questions will more than likely be closed because it is probably considered "trivia" for this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Truly [trivial](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0045152/trivia?item=tr1736154), but this happened back in *[Singin' in the Rain (1952)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0045152/)*...

> The movie begins with the premiere of Don Lockwood's latest picture,
>   "The Royal Rascal", a silent black-and-white adventure film. The
>   footage shown from "The Royal Rascal" is actually from a film MGM
>   released in 1948, [The Three Musketeers (1948), starring Gene Kelly](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0040876/) -
>   which is in color and has sound. For this film both color and sound
>   were taken out of the footage and title cards were added. The other
>   change was adding shots of Jean Hagen (who played diva Lina Lamont) in
>   place of "The Three Musketeers" leading lady, Lana Turner. If you look
>   closely, it is Lana--not Jean--opening the door when the spear hits
>   it. The ending of "The Royal Rascal" was shot on the same set used for
>   "The Three Musketeers".